# Android ActionBar items with collapseActionView in API lv 8

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I currently ran into problem with displaying actionbar items with `app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"` type. I want to display actionbar items in collapsible list. Everything works fine in high level apis, but when it comes to api lv 8 the action items are not shown at all. However they work if i change showAsAction to any other type than collapseActionView. Any ideas how to make it work normally as a collapsible list? I am extending ActionBarActivity in every activity and import related libs `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;` but it is still not working.

menu

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="About"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />
```

Activity onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pagrindinis, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Thanks for all the help!